# Взять элемент из Fragment Android

Tags: android, android-fragment

Допустим, у меня есть Fragment, а в нем иконка. Ее id `android:id="@+id/myIcon"`.

Этот фрагмент вместе с еще одним подключается в edit_activity.java. `fr1` - наш фрагмент.

```
//Pager
TabsViewPagerAdapter adapter = new TabsViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
adapter.addFragment(fr1, "1");
adapter.addFragment(fr2, "2");
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Подключили, да. Как мне **именно** в edit_activity получить эту иконку. То есть, допустим, обычный элемент я бы искал через `findViewById()`, а элемент из фрагмента?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В своем фрагменте в методе onCreateView:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView ) view.findViewById(R.id.myIcon);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: А никак нельзя сделать это в моем edit_activity? А то я не могу из этого класса обратиться, например, к тулбару